# How do you add a numbered or bulleted list in a table cell entry or line breaks

Tags: docbook-5

Docbook 5 trying to add a simplelist or single lines of text in a table row cell entry but cannot find the secret combination of allowed elements. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is valid according to my editor:

```
  <informaltable>
    <tgroup cols="1">
      <tbody>
        <row>
          <entry>
            <para>A single line of text</para>
            <simplelist>
              <member>Apiary</member>
              <member>Beekeeper</member>
            </simplelist>
          </entry>
        </row>
      </tbody>
    </tgroup>
  </informaltable>
```